# How to increase Variable value based on the iteration being run in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have an API request that I need to run in Postman-Collection-Runner thru multiple iterations. The API request uses Variable.

How can I make this variable to automatically increase with each iteration (or maybe set the iteration value as another Variable)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to assign different values to a variable in the request in different iterations which is achievable in 2 ways.

**a) Using data files**

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/working_with_data_files/

The data files could be in JSON or CSV format. Unfortunately, there is no way in Postman to tie the variable values to another variable unless you want to do it in a hacky way!

**b) Pre-request & Tests scripts**

1- Initialise the environment variable in the **Pre-request Scripts** like this:

```
var value = pm.environment.get("var");

if( !value) {
    pm.environment.set("var", 1);
}
```

2- Increment the variable value in **Tests**

```
var value = pm.environment.get("var");

pm.environment.set("var", value+1);
```

This creates an environment variable and increments it after each iteration. depending on how you structure your collection you might need to consider flushing/resetting the environment variable to be ready for the next run

It worth mentioning that **Pre-request Scripts** and **Tests** running before and after the requests respectively, so you can write any scripts that would like to run after the request in the **Tests**. It shouldn't be necessarily a test!

Comment: Thanks @Mehran. But I'm looking for something (probably) more simple. I do not want to use any data-files. But what I want is that my Variable i.e. {varId} starts from 10 for the first iteration, and then will increase *automatically* by +1 for every next iteration. Thus after 10s iteration the last valu will be '20' etc.

Comment: Thanks @Mehran! I think that is what I need. I'll give it a try.

Comment: One more question @Mehran, do you know if there is a way to set that `value` property back to null/empty at *the end of the iterations* (i.e. if I run it for 100 iterations, after the run #100 this property will be reset back to null)?

Comment: @KVN `pm.info.iteration` gives you the iteration number (starts from 0) and `pm.info.iterationCount` is for the total number of iterations. so a simple check in the **Tests** section will work. you probably need sth like this for it: `if (pm.info.iteration == pm.info.iterationCount-1){
    pm.environment.set("var", <TheDesiredFinalValue>);
}
else{
    var value = pm.environment.get("var");
    pm.environment.set("var", value+1);
}
`

Answer (score 14):

**1. Using Global `pm.*` functions and Variables in Pre-Request Scripts/Tests**

**Pre-Request script** - runs before executing the request

**Tests** - runs after executing the request

**a.**

```
pm.variables.set("id", pm.info.iteration);
```

Ex: **example.com/{{id}}/update** gives

**example.com/0/update**

**example.com/1/update** etc...

Number of iterations is set in Collection Runner. `pm.info.iteration` key has the current iteration number, starting at 0.

**b.**

```
var id = +pm.globals.get("id");
pm.globals.set("id", ++id);
```

The variables can be in any scope - `globals`/`collection`/`environment`/`local`/`data`.

In Collection Runner, check the `Keep Variable Values` checkbox, to persist the final value of the variable in the session (here `id`).

**Note:** If the variable is accessed via individual scopes (via `pm.globals.*` or `pm.environment.*` or `pm.collectionVariables.*`), then the mentioned checkbox should be toggled as required. Else if accessed via local scope (`pm.variables.*`), the value will not be persisted irrespective of the checkbox.

Ex: Same as above

[More on variables and scoping](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/variables-and-environments/variables/)

---

**2. Using Dynamic variables**

These variables can be used in case random values are needed or no specific order is necessary.

**a.** `$randomInt` - gives a random Integer within 1 - 1000.

Ex: **example.com/{{$randomInt}}/update** gives

**example.com/789/update**,

**example.com/265/update** etc...

**b.** `$timestamp` - gives current UNIX timestamp in seconds.

Ex: **example.com/{{$timestamp}}/update** gives

**example.com/1587489427/update**

**example.com/1587489434/update** etc...

[More on Dynamic variables](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/variables-and-environments/variables-list/)

---

Using Postman 7.22.1, while answering this. New methods may come in future.